# "Live" Webpage appears differently than the "offline" or "local" version

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js, web-frontend

I am working on my website, and everything is looking fine on the main site, but when I visit the Pong game that I've made, it looks and behaves differently than my local flies.

When I program, I paste the file path into Chrome and work on my game like that, when I am finished, I update the files that are hosted on a Hostwinds server. After I copy and paste my slightly more functional code into the files in the Hostwinds directory, there are differences.

In the online version, it's almost like my code didn't update at all. There are still bugs in the game that I fixed while editing offline. I'm not really sure what's going on, but I am certain that the files in the Hostwinds directory are exactly identical to the files on my local hard drive.

Heres the link to the site: http://www.grahambillington.com/pong/index.html

Comment: Clear the cache, or use incognito mode

Comment: This worked! Why is this the solution - I got this laptop today. Shouldn't the cash be relatively cleared?

Comment: Highly recommend reading up on how browser cache works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try a cache refresh. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> in Chrome.
2. Try Incognito mode or try a browser you rarely use. Microsoft Edge has its uses for this kind of debugging.
3. Check that you properly restarted your server if your deployment process requires it.
4. If you are using Git to move files to the server, check that you pushed your files correctly.

Comment: Refreshing the cash worked - but sometimes there are small little bugs that occur randomly, but when I refresh they go away. Any ideas?

Comment: @GrahamBillington can those bugs be reproduced again after the refresh or do they disappear for good?

Comment: I've seen the same bug a few times now - sometime the ball will phase right through the paddle, but after a refresh, it is back to normal.